# Should C++ function default argument values be specified in headers or .cpp source files?

Tags: c++, header

I am kind of new to C++. I am having trouble setting up my headers. This is
from functions.h

```
extern void apply_surface(int, int, SDL_Surface *, SDL_Surface *,SDL_Rect *);
```

And this is the function definition from functions.cpp

```
void
apply_surface(int x, int y, SDL_Surface * source, SDL_Surface *
destination,SDL_Rect *clip = NULL)
{
    ...
}
```

And this is how I use it in main.cpp

```
#include "functions.h"
int
main (int argc, char * argv[])
{
    apply_surface(bla,bla,bla,bla); // 4 arguments, since last one is optional.
}
```

But, this doesn't compile, because, main.cpp doesn't know last parameter is optional. How can I make this work?

Comment: have you tried adding to the header?

Answer (score 179, accepted):

You make the declaration (i.e. in the header file - `functions.h`) contain the optional parameter, not the definition (`functions.cpp`).

```
//functions.h
extern void apply_surface(int, int, SDL_Surface *, SDL_Surface *,SDL_Rect * clip = NULL);

//functions.cpp
void apply_surface(int x, int y, SDL_Surface * source, SDL_Surface *
destination,SDL_Rect *clip /*= NULL*/)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: To clarify, the declaration is the part in the header.

Comment: this is something i always confuse when setting up an empty c++ application, i really need to start using default-application setups

Answer (score 24):

The default parameter value should be in the function declaration (functions.h), rather than in the function definition (function.cpp).

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
extern void apply_surface(int, int, SDL_Surface *, SDL_Surface *,SDL_Rect * = NULL);
```

(note I can't check it here; don't have a compiler nearby).

Answer (score -4):

Strangely enough, it works fine for me if I have a virtual function without a default parameter, and then inheritors in .h files without default parameters, and then in their .cpp files I have the default parameters. Like this:

```
// in .h
class Base {virtual void func(int param){}};
class Inheritor : public Base {void func(int param);};
// in .cpp
void Inheritor::func(int param = 0){}
```

Pardon the shoddy formatting

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31138284)